# What is the difference between the :audio-playback & :audio-record and :pulseaudio snap slots?

Tags: permissions, snap, zoom-meeting

I installed the `zoom-client` snap application and while looking at the permissions in Software I noticed that there are three permissions that seem overlapping. There are "Play audio", "Record audio" and then there is "Play and record sound".

On running `snap connections zoom-client` I noticed that these slots are called `:audio-playback`, `:audio-record` and `:pulseaudio` respectively.

What is the difference between the first two and the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pulseaudio` is a legacy interface we don't use on the classic desktop anymore. It's been replaced by `audio-playback` and `audio-record`. `audio-playback` enables the application to play audio through sound interfaces. It's automatically connected on most environments. `audio-record` enables an application to have access to sound recording devices such as microphones - or microphones embedded in other devices like webcams. This one is not automatically connected by default. However for applications which use sound recording as a primary purpose - such as zoom - the publisher can request auto-connection, which they have.